# Verify a Color Has Been Inputted in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, datagridview

I have a datagridview where one of the columns is a color column. I want to ensure the user enters a valid color, otherwise leave the cell blank.

When the cell is starting from blank, the following code gives me a null reference exception. Fyi, I am doing this in the CellLeave event.

*Answer* I had to move the code to the CellFormatting event. For some reason, the value at the cell does not get updated until a certain unknown point. For my check, I need to do it before something I was doing in the CellFormatting event. Moving the code there fixed my problem.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex.Equals(2))
    {
        Regex test = new Regex("[0-255],[0-255],[0-255]");

        Match m = test.Match(this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());

        if(!m.Success)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the Color Dialogue?

Comment: I use that as a second way for the user to select the color. I also want them to be able to type in a (numeric) color of their choice.

Comment: Please take look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26531239/2878550) below where I show how properly update the cell's value in the CellParsing event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate a string you could use this method:

```
private static bool IsValidColorString(string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return false;
    string[] parts = input.Split(',');
    if (parts.Length != 3)
        return false;
    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        int val;
        if (!int.TryParse(part, out val) || val < 0 || val > 255)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The best place to use it I believe is the `DataGridView.CellParsing` event handler:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value == null || e.ColumnIndex != 2) // Skip empty cells and columns except #2
        return;
    string input = e.Value.ToString();
    if (!IsValidColorString(input))
        e.Value = String.Empty;  // An updated cells's value is set back to the `e.Value`
}
```

An updated cells's value is set back to the `e.Value` instead of the `DataGridView.CurrentCell.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your match:

```
Match m = test.Match((this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value ?? "").ToString());
```

This will replace a null value with an empty string when matching.

Comment: I think I am having a different problem. It looks like the value does not get updated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps need to check to see if there is a value within the cell before you try and match a Regex?

```
if (e.ColumnIndex.Equals(2))
{
  if(this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null)
  {
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

CurrentCell.Value.ToString()

Causing the error..

```
CurrentCell.value=null
```

null value can't cast using the tostring() method,that's why you are getting ther null reference exception.

try this..

```
string val="";
    if(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value==null)
{
val=""
}
els
else
{
val=convert.tostring(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.value);
}
Match m = test.Match(val);
 if(!m.Success)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "";
        }
```

Comment: yeah I found that out. The issue is, I change the value of the cell in the CellParsing event. However, by the time I go to another event, the cell data hasn't changed yet.

Comment: @user2970916, please take look at my answer below where I show how correctly update the cell's value in the `CellParsing` event handler.